# "Undo" after editing objects in a custom editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've made a custom editor (extends EditorWindow). This editor allows to edit the selected objects.

The problem is that after I press a button on the editor panel, pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>/<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>does nothing, it's not tracked in the history.

Is there some command that would enable to trace actions triggered from within a custom editor panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that but since unity doesn't automatically keeps track of objects modified by scripts, you have to inform the editor which object to record. You can rely on Unity's undo system for all serialized properties.

The steps are:

1. use [Undo.RecordObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Undo.RecordObject.html) to track an object before modifying it
2. modify a serializedproperty of the object
3. use [EditorUtility.SetDirty](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html) to flag the object as modified

Here's a simple example:

```
public class TestWindow : EditorWindow {

    static Transform anObjTransform;
    void OnGUI() 
    {

        anObjTransform = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField ("selected object", anObjTransform, typeof(Transform), true) as Transform;

        if (anObjTransform != null && GUILayout.Button("MOVE RIGHT"))
        {
            Undo.RecordObject(anObjTransform, "move");
            anObjTransform.Translate(anObjTransform.right * 10f);

            EditorUtility.SetDirty(anObjTransform);
        }
    }
    [MenuItem ("Test/Test Window")]
    private static void Init () {
        EditorWindow.GetWindow<TestWindow> ();

    }
}
```

Comment: change `static Transform anObjectTransform` to `static string aString` and `EditorGUILayout.ObjectField` to `EditorGUILayout.TextField`. Now how do I get Undo to work?

Comment: @gmam: I realize the posted example is a bit misleading. Undo system rely on object serialization, so usually you need a non static serializable field to use it. If aString would be a member of a serialized class you could retrieve the SerializedProperty relative. With a static string field of a non-serialized class (EditorWindow) I don't think there is anyway to use Undo. You can consider wrapping the field inside a component attached to a gameobject that won't be saved .

Comment: Undo works but the object isn't set as dirty when rolled back and isn't saved to disk.